# IOS App working on IOS Version 12.4.8 but not on 13.6.1

Tags: swift, soap

Hope you guys can help. I have an app that downloads files from a company Windows server that works on an iPhone 6 (V12.4.8) but crashes on an iPhone 8 (V13.6.1). I've been trying to work out why without any success. Any help you provide would be appreciated. The app crash shows -

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.'

This is the function it's failing at..... which is called from an alert controller:

```
    func DownloadFile(Path: String, DocName: String){
    let DocName2 = DocName.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "_")
    ParseAllData = true
    is_SoapMessage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><DownloadFile xmlns=\"LSM_Multiservices\"><Username>\(GlobalStart.Username)</Username><Password>\(GlobalStart.Password)</Password><DocName>\(DocName2)</DocName><FullPath>\(Path)</FullPath></DownloadFile></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"
    
    print(DocName)
    print(Path)
    
    let URL: String = GlobalSettings.ServerAddress
    let WebRequ = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: URL)! as URL)
    WebRequ.httpMethod = "POST"
    WebRequ.httpBody = is_SoapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    WebRequ.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    WebRequ.addValue(String(is_SoapMessage), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    var Str: String = ""
    
    let task = session.dataTask(with: WebRequ as URLRequest, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if data.self == nil{
            //self.CustomAlert(Message: "LSM Multiservices", Information: "Failed to contact server. Please try again.")
            self.ClearTasks()
            return
        }
        let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        Str = String(strData!) as String
        Str = Str.replacingOccurrences(of: "&lt;", with: "<")
        Str = Str.replacingOccurrences(of: "&gt;", with: ">")
        Str = Str.replacingOccurrences(of: "&amp;", with: "&")
        Str = Str.replacingOccurrences(of: "Invoice_No ", with: "Invoice_No")
        print(Str)
        print(Path)
        GlobalPRViewRecord.XMLData = Data(Str.utf8)
        
        
        if error != nil
        {
            print("Error: " + error.debugDescription)
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All code that modified the UI should be completed in UI thread
I guess in your case it's this

```
//self.CustomAlert(Message: "LSM Multiservices", Information: "Failed to 
       contact server. Please try again.")
        self.ClearTasks()
```

Wrap it into Main queue

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
   //self.CustomAlert(Message: "LSM Multiservices", Information: "Failed to 
           contact server. Please try again.")
            self.ClearTasks()
}
```

Comment: Hi Vitalii, just tried your suggestion and it still crashes with the same error unfortunately.